# allow read special character in angular from url

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i have this url :

```
http://localhost:4200/auth/verify-checking/?email=kiadr93721477@gmail.com&code=6XWK+4bpLA++2UfBr
```

in this url i have a params `code=6XWK+4bpLA++2UfBr` and in that url i have a special charcter like `+` .

i read the params by this code :

```
 constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router:Router) {
      this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        this.sendModel.email = params['email'];
        this.sendModel.code =  params['code'];
      });
  
  }
```

when i need to read the code and send it to server it send this code : `6XWK 4bpLA  2UfBr` but it must be like this `6XWK+4bpLA++2UfBr` and it replace the `+` by 'blank space' .

i create a custome url serlizer but it not worked and still have that problem :

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomUrlSerializer implements UrlSerializer {
  /** Parses a url into a {@link UrlTree} */
  private defaultSerializer: DefaultUrlSerializer = new DefaultUrlSerializer();

  /** Parses a url into a {@link UrlTree} */
  parse(url: string): UrlTree {

    // This is the custom patch where you'll collect segment containing '='
    const lastSlashIndex = url.lastIndexOf('/'), equalSignIndex = url.indexOf('=', lastSlashIndex);
    if (equalSignIndex > -1) { // url contians '=', apply patch
      const keyValArr = url.substr(lastSlashIndex + 1).split('=');
      const urlTree = this.defaultSerializer.parse(url);

      // Once you have serialized urlTree, you have two options to capture '=' part
      // Method 1. replace desired segment with whole "key=val" as segment
      urlTree.root.children['primary'].segments.forEach((segment: UrlSegment) => {
        if (segment.path === keyValArr[0]) {
          segment.path = keyValArr.join('='); // Suggestion: you can use other unique set of characters here too e.g. '$$$'
        }
      });

      // Method 2. This is the second method, insert a custom query parameter
      // urlTree.queryParams[keyValArr[0]] = keyValArr[1];
      return urlTree;
    } else {
      // return as usual
      return this.defaultSerializer.parse(url);
    }
  }

  /** Converts a {@link UrlTree} into a url */
  serialize(tree: UrlTree): string {
    return this.defaultSerializer.serialize(tree);
  }
}
```

and inject in provider in `core.module` :

```
    {
        provide: UrlSerializer,
        useClass: CustomUrlSerializer
    },
```

**whats the problem ? how can i solve this problem ????**

Comment: As you have already pointed out `+` is a special character in URI, so if you have control over generating side of this urls, you can use `encodeURIComponent` to make `code` value safe

Comment: @RPasha please give me more explain . i can undestand you guide

Comment: Assuming this URL is generated from back-end and you have control over it's code, use 
`encodeURIComponent` or `encodeURI ` or something similar in your back-end language to make generated URL safe

Comment: so, your safe URL would be: `http://localhost:4200/auth/verify-checking/?email=kiadr93721477%40gmail.com&code=6XWK%2B4bpLA%2B%2B2UfBr`

Comment: @RPasha this way have a problem . i must send this exactly this code in to server . but the encodeURIComponent  conver spcial chrarcter to %3D ot etc but i need send exactly `+` to server

Comment: this is a URI standard and all  url parser recognize this protocol and will decode it back to  `6XWK+4bpLA++2UfBr`.

Comment: @RPasha when i decode that still replce`+` to  `blank`

Answer (score 0):

I beleive the problem lies when you are passing the value. As you haven't shown that I made a working example which works with query params without the need of any serializers.

**Working Example:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-navigate-with-query-params-cutzfm

Comment: i,m not pass the query params from into the angular . this link send by server to email and when click on the link in email it come into the page .

Comment: I am having trouble understanding what you wrote. kindly revise

Comment: The problem is how you are sending the link on email. Its should be URL encoded when send to email like this: =   https://angular-navigate-with-query-params-cutzfm.stackblitz.io/authenticate?jwt=1236XWK%2B4bpLA%2B%2B2UfBr

Comment: This url , which contains the code (code includes certain characters), is sent to the user's email via the server, and the user enters the page by clicking on the link, and when loading that page, I have to extract the code from the url, and this problem occurs when extracting the code. It happens.

Comment: The problem is when sending from server it should be send urlencoded

Comment: how is it saved in sever? from angular or manually ?

Comment: serve auto generate the code and save into the database and then send that link to email

Comment: how does it autogenerate Angular route links? i feel like they are hardcoded links in Server

Comment: server just generate the code . the angular routering is manually . . `localhost:4200/reset-password` + `generate code`

Comment: alright got it . You need to URLencode the code from server before sending it to Angular. What server and database are you using?

Comment: aspcore and sql server

Comment: Alright just handle it in angular. If you console.log the generate code from localhost:4200/reset-password + generate code does it print properly?

Comment: it print with out the +

Comment: If it is saved in the database! set the column in the table where it is saved to nvarchar, it should solve the problem